# Construct the unitary from the given unitary operator conjugation operator

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra (or just consider $B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$). Now for a given $T\in \text{Aut}(A)$ and $T$ is of this form:
$$T(x)=uxu^*$$
for some unitary $u\in A$, $x\in A$. (We only know $T$ but not $u$.) Can we construct $u$ from $T$? In other word, is there a certain way to construct a unitary $u$ from the given $T$ and 
if $T(x)=vxv^*$ for some other unitary $v\in A$, then $v=\theta u$ for some $\theta\in\mathbb{C},|\theta|=1$?

Comment: How do we know that all automorphisms $T$ are of the form $T(x) =uxu^*$? Doesn't the proof produce $u$ for $T$?

Comment: It is not true that every $C^*$ algebra is of the form $B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$. Consider for example $C(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $X$. Moreover algebras of this type typically admit plenty of automorphisms, which can't possibly be inner.

Comment: I did not mean that all automorphism is of conjugate form and I did not mean that all C*-algebra is $B(H)$.

Comment: Just say $T:A\to A$, we know the input and output of $T$, and $T$ should be in the conjugate form, then the question is whether we can construct such $u$ from $T$ and the uniqueness up to scalar.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of $B(H)$, consider $x = e_j e_k^*$ where $\{e_i\}$ are an orthonormal basis of $H$.  Then $u x u^* = (u e_j)(u e_k)^*$.  Thus $u e_j$ is a unit vector that is a scalar multiple of $(u x u^*) w$ for any $w \in H$ such that $(u x u^*) w \ne 0$.

EDIT: First try $j=k$: $T(e_j e_j^*)$ must be of the form $v_j v_j^*$ for some unit vector $v_j$, which $v_j v_j^*$ determines up to multiplication by a scalar of absolute value $1$.  Then $T(e_j e_k^*) = v_j v_k^*$.  This determines the scalar for $v_k$ relative to that for $v_j$.  Thus everything is determined up to one scalar.

Comment: I don't know how you construct $u$ from $T$.